# What is the meaning of "nonuniformly scaled texture" in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sktexture, skcropnode

On `SKCropNode` class reference, some examples to specify a mask are given.

Here they are:

> This means a crop node can use simple masks derived from a piece of artwork, but it can also use more sophisticated masks. For example, here are some ways you might specify a mask:
>
> - An untextured sprite that limits content to a rectangular portion of the scene.
> - A textured sprite is a precise per-pixel mask. But consider also the benefits of a nonuniformly scaled texture. You could use a nonuniformly scaled texture to create a mask for a resizable user-interface element (such as a health bar) and then fill the masked area with dynamic content.
> - A collection of nodes can dynamically generate a complex mask that changes each time the frame is rendered.

The second example introduce *nonuniformly scaled texture*: what's the meaning of this?

This does not help me to understand this second example!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-uniformly scaled texture is a texture that is applied to a sprite with `xScale` != `yScale`.